# Using AlarmManager to perform a specific task in future

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, toast

I am new to Android and I would appreciate any help on this.

I am trying to use Alarm Manager so that it would call my `BroadcastReceiver` class at a specific time in future set by `DatePicker` and `TimePicker` widgets.

However, i cannot get the broadcastreceiver class to perform its function.

below is the code that i put in the manifest file for the broadcastreceiver class to receive the broadcast message from OS:

```
    <receiver android:name="androidapp.scheduler.MyBroadcastReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MYBROADCASTRECEIVER" >
            </action>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

And below is the code that i have put in my Next button's onclicklistener so that it would inform OS of the time of the call.

```
            TimePicker myTp = (TimePicker)findViewById(R.id.tpTime);
            cal.set(Calendar.YEAR,myDatePicker.getYear() );
            cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, myDatePicker.getMonth());
            cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, myDatePicker.getDayOfMonth());
            cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, myTp.getCurrentHour());
            cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, myTp.getCurrentMinute());
            cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

            Log.i("SCheduling", cal.getTime().toString());

            Intent intent = new Intent(Scheduling.this, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Scheduling.this, 234324243, intent, 0);
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

            Intent nextForm = new Intent(this,Sender.class);
            nextForm.putExtra("contacts", contacts);
            startActivity(nextForm);    
            Log.i("SCheduling", "everything set");
```

Finally, `MybroadcastReceivers` class code is shown below:

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i("brreceiver", "BroadcastReciever");
        Toast.makeText(context, "schedule set!.",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: I am wondering what the Toast is receiving as context.  Is it the correct context?  The reason i am asking this is that after the date has been set, my program loads the next activity which is sender.class.  However, the Toast is not appearing?

Comment: is the broadcast received, did you check the log to see if OnReceive is called

Comment: yes i checked the logs and there was none.

Answer (score 0):

In the following statement change Scheduling.this to this.getApplicationContext()

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Scheduling.this, 234324243, intent, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems the code was correct, the problem was with the Emulator. I still don't know what was wrong with the emulator but i tested the code again and it worked and i did receive the log's output.